# Old school border image - css2 -

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, html-table, border

I have an issue with creating boxshadows..
I am working in IE8 and hence I cannot use CSS3 - nor does CSSPIE help as it basically screws up my boxshadow when uploading to SharePoint (2007) (pie works fine in IE8, outside of SharePoint).
My new approach is to create a table with border images - like in the old days, but somehow it looks odd..

This is the code I have:

```
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
    <TBODY>
     <TR>
      <TD style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: bottom; WIDTH: 10px; HEIGHT: 10px"><IMG height=10 alt="" src="lefttopcorner.png" border="0" width=10>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD style="BACKGROUND-POSITION: 50% bottom; BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(topside.png); BACKGROUND-REPEAT: repeat-x; HEIGHT: 10px">&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD style="VERTICAL-ALIGN:bottom; WIDTH: 10px; HEIGHT: 10px"><IMG height=10 alt="" src="righttopcorner.png" width=10 border="0">&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(leftside.png); VERTICAL-ALIGN: bottom; BACKGROUND-REPEAT: repeat-y; HEIGHT: 10px">&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #F4F3F2"> &nbsp;&nbsp; </TD>
      <TD style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(rightside.png); VERTICAL-ALIGN: bottom; BACKGROUND-REPEAT: repeat-y; HEIGHT: 10px">&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
      <TD style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; WIDTH: 10px; HEIGHT: 10px"><IMG height=10 alt="" src="leftbottomcorner.png" width=10>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD style="BACKGROUND-POSITION:50%; BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(bottomside.png); BACKGROUND-REPEAT: repeat-x; HEIGHT: 10px">&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; WIDTH: 10px; HEIGHT: 10px"><IMG height=10 alt="" src="rightbottomcorner.png" width=10>&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
     </TR>
   </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

The table doesn't seem to become a coherent box:

[image: http://imgur.com/4ARd5tL]

and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cz29T/ however, I don't have the slightest clue how to upload images to a fiddle..

If there is a CSS solution - NOT CSS3 please - then I'd like to know :)

I will greatly appreciate if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.. it is probably a rookie mistake, but right now I think I have looked at it for too long..

Comment: Images would really help. Just use imgur and post the URLs.

Comment: can you http://jsfiddle.net this thing

Comment: image link now in post! :) still working on that fiddle thing :D

Comment: @David - did you want the images for the borders? the tiny ones? :)

Comment: @VivekVikranth - i made a fiddle..

Comment: @user3035814 No just an image of the problem

Comment: @user3035814 man update the url of your images..

Comment: haha ofcourse i could just upload all of them to imgur and link.. sorry - i have never used any before :)

Comment: @VivekVikranth - there... now i relinked the images... seem to me though, that it still doesnt work :)

Comment: @David - the imgur link is an img of the outcome

Comment: Guys? are you there? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `filter` property for IE.

You can refer URL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx">Link

Example of box-shadow for IE :

```
.class{
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=150, Color='#333333');
}
```

You can change `Direction` value to 90, 180, 270, 360 to show shadow for complte box.

I have created a sample code which consists of `Border` as well as `box-shadow`.
Please check if it works.

```
<Div class="CheckShadow">
Try Box Shadow
</Div>

<style>
.CheckShadow
{
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    box-shadow:4px 4px 5px red; 
    border:5px solid blue;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=red,direction=90,strength=10),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=red,direction=180,strength=10);
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks! this definately creates a shadow - however it seems like it also kills my border style :D

Comment: but, actually, you didn't solve my problem ? well i did get some shadows, but my borders dissapeared?

Comment: so you sisn't really solve my problem? unless this filter thing can restore my 5 px border :/

Comment: I am trying that out. I will try provide solution in sometime.

Comment: I dont reallt know what you are trying to do with this code? it really does nothing than adding a red shadow? my border is still gone :/

Comment: ok so I tried it in a fiddle... is there any way to get the shadow all around the box?

Comment: i am trying to get the shadow on a <td> and you are doing it to a <div> somehow it is not working on a <td> as on a <div>

Comment: Yes. You can specify the angles where you need shadow. Direction can be specified from 0 degree to 360 degrees. In above example I have used 90 and 180 degree.

Comment: Use -ms-filter in place of filter to show box shadow for version IE8+.

Comment: like this? : -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=90, Color='#98B2E3'); - does not work either :/